# How to generate Density Functional Tight Binding parameters (Slater-Koster files)?

Tags: computational-chemistry

What is the simplest way (or least complicated way) to generate parameter files (.skf) to be used with DFTB+, for example?

Assuming I want to be able to reproduce geometries for a certain type of molecules, how would I go about it?

Comment: There is no reliable black-box method for SK parameters. There are some useful tools, but even with those a reliable parameter set requires lot of work.

Comment: Do you care to elaborate on the useful tools and the kind of work required?

Comment: You can check out Hotbit (https://github.com/pekkosk/hotbit) and corresponding documentation and code examples, or automatic ("automatic"?) parametrization by SKOPT (https://bitbucket.org/stanmarkov/skopt/src/master/) or adpt_core (https://bitbucket.org/solccp/adpt_core/src/master/).